# call dao in another for sqlite transaction

Tags: android, sqlite, dao

i have 2 dao and i need to call method between them

I did something like this but it s really bad because it does a infinite loop and it's does not respect quality standard 
What is the proper way to do this please ?
Thank you very much

DAO 1

```
public class InfractionDAO {


  private SQLiteDatabase database;
  private SqLiteManager dbHelper;
  private OffenderDAO offenderDAO;


  public InfractionDAO(Context context) {
    dbHelper = new SqLiteManager(context);
    offenderDAO= new OffenderDAO (context);
  }

  List<Infractions> getInfractions(int id) {
     offenderDao.getOffender(id);
  }
}
```

DAO 2

```
public class OffenderDAO {


  private SQLiteDatabase database;
  private SqLiteManager dbHelper;
  private InfractionDAO infractionDAO;

  public OffenderDAO (Context context) {
    dbHelper = new SqLiteManager(context);
    infractionDAO = new InfractionDAO(context);
  }

 Offender getOffender(int id) {
  infractionDAO.getInfractions(id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do, is the following: 
Solution 1. 
create a base class(maybe make abstract?) for both, where they share the common things and in each of the separate classes, offernder and infraction put the different stuff. 

 Solution 2. 
I would create a singleton class that in the constructor initializes both.
like in the following linke:
http://pastebin.com/84g9SgFT

Comment: thank you very much .the solution 1 is way better and cleaner :)